# Opensource Angular tree component

Tags: angular, web, angular6, angular7

**Is there any opensource library in Angular 6 or Angular 7 that supports Tree grid?**

I am searching for an opensource library that can be directly imported as a component,

The tree grid also must support dynamic data and must be getting generated in runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been using this opensource library for a while now checkout [this](https://github.com/debabratapatra/ngtreegrid).

NPM: [Click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngtreegrid)
Demo: [Click here](https://ng-tree-grid.stackblitz.io/)